# Runtime comparison of Swift Protocol MetaTypes

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to dynamically match a Swift protocol to an implementation, but I've gotten blocked on trying to perform comparisons of Protocols at runtime - it seems that maybe protocols don't really exist at runtime?

Some examples of things I've tried:

```
var protocols[Any]

func findProtocol(aProtocol: Any) -> Bool {
    // Nope, protocols don't implement equatable
    aProtocol == protocols[0]

    // Doesn't work, unsafeAddressOf() only applies to AnyObjects
    let pointer: UnsafePointer = unsafeAddressOf(aProtocol) 

}
```

I think I might have hit the boundaries of trying to defeat the type system... any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are actually filling that protocols array?

Comment: Would that be `ProtocolName.self`?

Comment: Do you have instances of types which conforms to the protocol or the types itself (`SomeProtocol.self`) in your array ?

Comment: @BenKane yes, currently I'm using .self to fill whatever structure I end up using.  I'd rather use a dictionary, but I hadn't found a good means to do so

Comment: @JRaymond Ok, can you take a look at my answer and see if that's what you're looking for? I wasn't sure if you would be passing a protocol to the method or an object conforming to a protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you compare the types themselves you should use a more appropriate type (`Any.Type`):

```
var protocolArray: [Any.Type] = [...]

func findProtocol(aProtocol: Any.Type) -> Bool {
    // you can do that because Any.Type has an == operator
    return protocolArray.contains{ $0 == aProtocol }
}
```

For `Any` type you have to cast it:

```
var protocolArray: [Any] = [...]

func findProtocol(aProtocol: Any) -> Bool {
    return protocolArray.contains{
        if let p1 = $0 as? Any.Type, p2 = aProtocol as? Any.Type {
            return p1 == p2
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't necessarily have real implementations of the types at this point - all I know is i have a protocol for which I'm asking an implementation.  The implementation types are registered when I add the protocols to the array in question; but the caller doesn't know the concrete type coming back

Comment: This works well also - I guess I had assumed that the Type would fall apart after casting

Answer (score 1):

I may be slightly misunderstanding what you're looking to do, but you should be able to use reflection for this. How about something like this?

```
protocol One {}
protocol Two {}
protocol Three {}

var protocols: [Any] = [One.self, Two.self]

func findProtocol(aProtocol: Any) -> Bool {

    let findMirror = Mirror(reflecting: aProtocol)

    for checkProtocol in protocols {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: checkProtocol)

        if findMirror.subjectType == mirror.subjectType {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

findProtocol(One) // Returns true
findProtocol(Two) // Returns true
findProtocol(Three) // Returns false
```

Comment: Seems to be doing the trick... I'll have to investigate to see if the returned subjectType is a unique pointer; it would be convenient to hash them instead of looping

Comment: This seemed to work initially (certainly it compiles) but I couldn't get it to work at runtime.  Maybe it only works in a playground?

Comment: Interesting. Had I known you were going to put Any.Type into the array I wouldn't have done it this way. @Qbyte's answer is more correct in that situation. All I did was get the underlying Any.Type anyway an compare them with this reflection approach.

Comment: I wasn't planning on it, I had Any in there originally - I just needed some way of storing/indexing the protocol at runtime.  Thanks though!